# I need to insert rows in bulk like in 1000's using triggers having different value in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Teacher]
ON [dbo].[Teacher]
After INSERT
AS

Declare @fid int, @PR NVARCHAR(MAX),@Mycounter  as INT
Select top 1 @fid = eid from human where TypeID = 2 
order by NewID()

Select top 1 @PR = Pid from [dbo].[Program] Where Depid = 1
order by NewID()

Set @Mycounter =1
While @Mycounter <5

BEGIN
    Insert Into HeadofDep(SessionID,fid,pid,name,createddate)
    Select SessionID, @fid,@PR,NULL,null from INSERTED
    Where eid in (Select eid from human where TypeID = 3)
set @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1; 
END
```

I need to insert 1000's of rows in `HeadofDep` table when any row is inserted in Teacher table. I have done by applying looping but all rows that get inserted in `HeadofDep` table have same `@PR`. Need it different against each row. 
Also need `sessionid` incremented.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: That trigger seems very flawed. Why are you setting values from a completely different table to variables, and why is it a random value?

Comment: @larnu which random value?

Comment: These random values, @Amna : `Select top 1 @fid = eid from human where TypeID = 2 
order by NewID()` & `Select top 1 @PR = Pid from [dbo].[Program] Where Depid = 1
order by NewID()`

Comment: @larnu For `@fid` : It is because in my system we have defined different groups of human like teacher, Driver, Maid, Agent etc So when any row is inserted in teacher i want to insert from type id 2 that is junior teachers group(includes Assistant teacher, Lecturer etc.)
 and for `@PR` the teacher is assigned to different programs from `depid 1` so select any random program from `dep id 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just, increment the `SessionID` then and put the other stuff in the loop:

```
Declare @fid int, @PR NVARCHAR(MAX),@Mycounter  as INT

Set @Mycounter =1
While @Mycounter <5

BEGIN
Select top 1 @fid = eid from human where TypeID = 2 
order by NewID()

Select top 1 @PR = Pid from [dbo].[Program] Where Depid = 1
order by NewID()

    Insert Into HeadofDep(SessionID,fid,pid,name,createddate)
    Select SessionID, @fid,@PR,NULL,null from INSERTED
    Where eid in (Select eid from human where TypeID = 3)
set @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1; 
END
```

Also, doing such LOOPs in triggers is bad.In this case, you can change 1000 inserts with one like this:

```
Insert Into HeadofDep(SessionID,fid,pid,name,createddate)
Select SessionID + N, @fid,@PR,NULL,null 
from INSERTED
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (1000) -1+row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
    FROM master..spt_values t1 
        CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
) DS 
Where eid in (Select eid from human where TypeID = 3)
```